# LightGBM predict_proba in thousandths place

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, lightgbm

Can someone explain to me how my lightgbm classification model's predict_proba() is in thousandths place for the positive class:

```
prob_test = model.predict_proba(X_test)

print(prob_test[:,1])
    
array([0.00219813, 0.00170795, 0.00125507, ..., 0.00248431, 0.00150855,
       0.00185903])
```

Is this common/how is this calculated?

Should there be concern on performance testing(AUC)?

FYI: data is highly imbalanced train = 0.0017 ratio

Comment: Is your `X_test` imbalanced too? Your model seems to predict mostly negative classes with high probabilities. And yes, this is common if your data is imbalanced, or you overfit to negative samples from training data.

Comment: yes it is imbalanced as well.  Overfitting at least from the test-valid delta seems small. Valid AUC = .653 | Test AUC = .644